# How to figure out what is requesting access to my yubikey?

Tags: gnupg, yubikey

I recently set up two yubikeys based on [this](https://github.com/drduh/YubiKey-Guide) guide. I also set it up so `gpg-agent` is my `ssh-agent`, so I can use the keys for ssh. For some reason, even without me taking any action after plugging in the key (or rebooting, or coming back from sleep) I will receive the yubikey pin prompt and the key will start blinking, indicating it needs user input. How can I figure out what is causing this? Are there some logs for gpg I could look at?

I also noticed that gpg-agent process will be respawned immediately if I kill it. I'm running Ubuntu 22.04.